# ASP.NET - response.outputstream.write either writes 16k and then all 0's, or writes all but insetrs a char every 64k

Tags: asp.net, zip

I have the following code...

```
public partial class DownloadFile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FilePath = "[FTPPath]";
        Download downloadFile = new Download();
        Server.ScriptTimeout = 54000;

        try
        {
            long size = downloadFile.GetFileSize(FilePath);

            using (FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = downloadFile.BrowserDownload(FilePath))
            using (Stream streamResponse = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                string fileName = FilePath.Substring(FilePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                int bufferSize = 65536;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int readCount;

                readCount = streamResponse.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                // Read file into buffer
                //streamResponse.Read(buffer, 0, (int)size);

                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = false;
                Response.BufferOutput = false;

                //Apparently this line helps with old version of IE that like to cache stuff no matter how much you tell them!
                Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");

                //Expires: 0 forces the browser to always thing the page is "stale" therefore forcing it to never cache the page and therefore always re-downloads the page when viewed. Therefore no nasty experiences if we change the authentication details.
                Response.Expires = 0;

                //Again this line forces the browser not to cache the page.
                Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
                Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");

                Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", size.ToString());

                // writes buffer to OutputStream
                while (readCount > 0)
                {
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    readCount = streamResponse.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    Response.Flush();
                }

                Response.End();
                Server.ScriptTimeout = 90;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<p>" + ex.Message + "</p>");
            Server.ScriptTimeout = 90;
        }
    }
}
```

To download .zip files from an FTP (please ignore the header rubbish about preventing caching unless this is related to the issue).

So `downloadFile` is a class I have written using `FTPWebRequest`/`Response` with SSL enabled that can do to two things; one is return the file size (`GetFileSize`) of a file on our FTP and the other is to set `FtpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile` to allow the download of a file.

Now the code appears to work perfectly, you get a nice zip downloaded of exactly the same size as the one on the FTP however, this is where the quirks begin.

The zip files are always corrupted, no matter how small. In theory, very small files should be okay, but you'll see why in a moment. Because of this, I decided to compare the files in binary.

- If I set `bufferSize` to anything other than the size of the file
  (i.e. 1024, 2048, 65536), the first 16k (16384 bytes) downloads
  perfectly, and then the stream just writes zeros to the end of the
  file.
- If I set `bufferSize = size` (filesize), the stream appears to download the full file, until you look more closely. The file is an exact replica up to the first 64k, and then an extra character appears in the downloaded file (this chararacter never seems to be the same).

  After this extra byte, the files are exactly the same again. An extra byte appears to get added every 64k, meaning that by the end of 65MB file, the two files are massively out of sync. Because the download length is limited to the size of the file on the server, the end of the file gets truncated in the downloaded file. The archive will allow access to it as all the CRC checks fail.

Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Now changed my code somewhat to use `WebRequest` and `WebResponse` to grabe a zip using Http from the web server itself. Here is the code...

```
public partial class DownloadFile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string FilePath = [http path];
    Server.ScriptTimeout = 54000;
    try
    {
        WebRequest HWR = WebRequest.Create(FilePath);
        HWR.Method = WebRequestMethods.File.DownloadFile;

        using (WebResponse FWR = HWR.GetResponse())
        using (BinaryReader streamResponse = new BinaryReader(FWR.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string fileName = FilePath.Substring(FilePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            int bufferSize = 2048;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int readCount;

            readCount = streamResponse.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.BufferOutput = false;
            //Apparently this line helps with old version of IE that like to cache stuff no matter how much you tell them!
            Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
            //Expires: 0 forces the browser to always thing the page is "stale" therefore forcing it to never cache the page and therefore always re-downloads the page when viewed. Therefore no nasty experiences if we change the authentication details.
            Response.Expires = 0;
            //Again this line forces the browser not to cache the page.
            Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
            Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

            // writes buffer to OutputStream
            while (readCount > 0)
            {
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                Response.Flush();
                readCount = streamResponse.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            //Response.Write(testString);
            Response.End();
            Server.ScriptTimeout = 90;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("<p>" + ex.Message + "</p>");
        Server.ScriptTimeout = 90;
    }
}
}
```

This code is more simple but it is still corrupting the data. I'm sure there's something very simple I'm doing wrong, but I just can't spot it or find a test to show me where I am going wrong. Please help :)

Comment: Any reason you are using a Page for this, a [HTTPHandler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) is much better suited.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...

Treat me with Kid gloves, I'm learning rather on the hoof here :) I assume by Page you mean that the version of response I'm using is defined in the Page object, how would I use the HTTPHandler version? What makes HTTPHandler better?

All the code I've used has largely been gleaned from site like this one, no formal training, except some books I've read.

Comment: I was trying to put some coed in here and it looked rubbish...i'll put it as an aswer as it does part answer my problem!

Comment: Oh hang I can;t for another 5 hours because I'm a new user!!! Basically switching the Response.Flush(); and the readCount=.... lines stops the truncation (because your adding new code to the buffer and then flushing it before it's written). But the extra char every 64K still exists.

Comment: @Matty W - What Richard is referring to is that your code inherits from Page rather than HttpHandler. Since you likely don't need all the overhead that comes with a Page (lifecycle, etc.) inheriting from HttpHandler would be a better option.

Comment: If you investigate streamResponse variable (before sending the content to a client) - is the zip ok? It sounds like encoding issue that gives an incorrect amount of bytes for the file, so maybe this happens before you dispatching the file further to browser...

Comment: @jesus.tesh - ok so if my code inherited from HttpHandler instead of page (the visual web dev default), would that just reduce the overhead, or would it help with my problem?

Comment: @Arthur P - By inverstigate, do you mean write streamResponse to a file? I do agree though, it could be an encoding issue, I just wish I knew which formats add a char every 64k so I could narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Matty: Have you tried writing the file from the FTP to a file stream on the server itself? You might wanna narrow down if it's something up with the FTP retrieval or if it's definitely ASP's problem

Comment: @rossisdead: I have now, so if I create a new Stream streamWriter and do streamResponse.CopyTo(streamWriter); the zip file is created perfectly on the server. Therefore the extra bites are getting added when streamResponse is being written by Response.OutputStream.Write using the buffer. I've tried streamResponse.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream), but this fails with a can't read the file error in Firefox/a connection reset in IE.

Comment: @Matty: Good to know. Have you tried using Response.TransmitFile? Given, you would need to first save the file locally, but it might also perform better than if you're keeping the ftp file in memory the whole time.

Comment: @rossisdead: It would be ideal to have the files esier to get to than on an FTP, unfortunately that's what the situation we're stuck and I can't change it (not up to me). Only the buffer is stored in memory, i've checked this by watching task manager, 65MB i fairly easy to see!

Comment: @Matty: Right right, I just meant having to save the file locally from the ftp on request, then call Response.TransmiteFile. You could then delete the locally stored file

Comment: @rossisdead: Ok, little secret :) I'm using the 65MB file in testing because it's the smallest one...we go upto 5GB...so copying it to the web server and then streaming it to the client would take far too long, especially if several people were after the same file :) Hence I need to fix the problem above because the powers that be can't/dont wanna/haven't got the money to change :)

Comment: More testing - I have output the buffer to a string using foreach (byte b in buffer) testString =+ b; I only cylced through the read buffer 50 times in order to keep the string small but to get at least 64k into the string. I then output the string using Response.Write(testString). Having converted the hex in the zip file to decimal for the 16 bytes before 64k, I then used find in the browser to find the same substring of binary just before 64k. Again I could see that this method had added an extra byte at 64k. Therefore this rules out Response.OutputStream.Write being the problem. Continued..

Comment: Continuation... The byte is getting added either by the buffer byte array or by buffering streamResponse. I'm not sure how I can check whether it's the buffer or streamResponse as it's a bit chicken an egg. I can't read what's coming out of streamResponse without using a bufer. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using the Response.WriteFile(tempPath); method instead or iterating on the buffer array and writing it to the output stream ?

Comment: @AMember: No I haven;t tried using this...wouldn;t this create a double download? First grab the file from the FTP and then download the file? I'm a little concerned that this would take forever for a 5GB file.

Comment: this should not create a double download... as it is not different from what you are doing now. give it a try and let me know how it go.

Comment: @AMember: I'm a complete novice at this so where would you suggest the temp path points to, somewhere on the web server or somewhere on the client? If it is on the client, how do I choose a temp location that is OS independant (Win/Mac/etc)? How do I link up the temp file with the temp file with the browser Save As dialog so that the user can choose where to save the file? I've never seen the temp path method on any other forum, so some pointers would be very useful. :)

Comment: Response.WriteFile and Response.TransmitFile both take a file path, so you'd end up having to store it locally from the ftp before you could send it to the client. Have you looked to see if your server is sending out the data with the transfer-encoding: chunked header? If so, I think that may be a problem, though I'm not sure

Comment: @rossisdead: That's what I thought, so I would have to download the file to the server first and then pass it onto the client and therefore passing that file to the client would still require chunking to avoid memory bloat? (Just making sure) Transfer-encoding: chunked looks interesting, I may test that tomorrow amoungst the miriad of other hair brained ideas I have! Many thanks for all the suggestions so far :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your line

```
Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
```

change bufferSize to readCount so that you only write the number that you actually read.

Comment: Just to confirm Chris, this was indeed the source of the problem. I understand what `Response.OutputStream.Write` is actually trying to do now. `buffersize` is the maximum read the stream should make (to not overflow the buffer) however, it may well fail to read the full amount of bytes and this is why it returns `readCount` so that you know how much of your buffer is valid. Many thanks again Chris :)